# "Did not" or "would not" for results

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality-in-context

> All he was looking for was *peace of mind*. And he did many things to attain that. He read various western intellects but *peace of mind* **would not** come.

I heard these words in a documentary film made in 1980's on a famous personality.

I am rather confused about the **would not**. As a modern learner I would have used **did not** in this context.

Is it a matter of **formality?**

Please explain.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

*Would not come* = refused to come (speaking as though 'peace of mind' had a will of its own).

This is one of the various different uses of *would*. Here it is the past tense of *will* in the sense of *am determined to.*

'My cat *will* keep scratching.'

'Last year my cat *would* keep scratching.'

'Last year my cat *would not* stop scratching.'